# How to delete duplicate data from postgres table, while only one or two columns have duplicates?

Tags: sql, postgresql, duplicates

I have a table with duplicate data in one or two columns. I want to delete duplicate data and keep one record only.

I tried the following code, but it deleted all of the data from my table.

```
DELETE from test del 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM test ex
        WHERE ex.name= del.name      
        );
```

Comment: update your question add  a proper data sample and the expected  result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If there is no primary key, the trick to discriminate duplicate rows is to use [`ctid`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-system-columns.html), the pseudo-column that identifies the (non-durable) physical location of the row.
Two rows cannot have the same `ctid`, and `ctid` can be compared to each other.

The following query adds the condition to discriminate the rows to delete against the one to keep, for each duplicate.

```
DELETE from test del 
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM test ex
        WHERE ex.name= del.name
          AND ex.ctid > del.ctid
        );
```

Answer (score 0):

If your data has a primary key, then you can do:

```
delete from test t
    where t.pk in (select min(t2.pk) from test t2 group by t2.name);
```